# Find the first 3 year period with at least 3 events?

Tags: python

I have a list of events with timestamps:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date

@dataclass
class Event:
    start: date

events = [
    Event(date(2001, 10, 1)),
    Event(date(2002, 9, 1)),
    Event(date(2005, 8, 1)),
    Event(date(2006, 7, 1)),
    Event(date(2007, 6, 1)),
    Event(date(2008, 5, 1)),
    Event(date(2009, 4, 1)),
]
```

I want to find the events in the first 3-year period that has at least 3 events, ie. 2005, 2006, 2007, and 2008 in the example.

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: what if you have events on the same year, like `2001`, `2001`, and `2002`

Comment: As long as the last `Event.start` is less than 3 years after the first `Event.start` they would count. In the example there are 4 events in the first 3-year period that has at least 3 events.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a helper function to iterate over the list of `Event` objects like below. I'm honestly not sure if it's the most efficient approach, but it should be `O(N)` time complexity in any case, since it only needs to iterate over the list once at most.

> **Warning:** this function will mutate the input `events` object as it is currently written. If this is not desired, one option is to use list unpacking like `first_event, *events = events` to split the split the list by the first index value.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import date, timedelta


@dataclass
class Event:
    start: date

events = [
    Event(date(2001, 10, 1)),
    Event(date(2002, 9, 1)),
    Event(date(2005, 8, 1)),
    Event(date(2005, 9, 1)),
    # try changing following year to 2009
    Event(date(2008, 6, 1)),
    Event(date(2010, 5, 1)),
    Event(date(2012, 4, 1)),
]


def find_start_year(events: list[Event], max_yr_period: int = 3) -> int | None:
    """
    find the start year of a 3-year consecutive period, in a list of events
    which are sorted by year.
    """
    pd_start_date: date = events.pop(0).start
    pd_start_yr: int | None = pd_start_date.year

    max_diff = timedelta(days=365 * max_yr_period)
    consecutive_yrs = 1

    for e in events:
        e_start_date = e.start
        year_diff: timedelta = e_start_date - pd_start_date

        if year_diff > max_diff:
            pd_start_date = e_start_date
            pd_start_yr = e_start_date.year
            consecutive_yrs = 1
        else:
            consecutive_yrs += 1
            if consecutive_yrs == max_yr_period:
                break
    else:  # no 3-year period with consecutive events
        pd_start_yr = None

    return pd_start_yr


print(find_start_year(events))
```

Out:

```
 2005
```